# User cannot login using gradlew. Same permissions as another user who can

Tags: android-gradle-plugin, artifactory, gradlew

Since I set up [JFrog Artifactory](https://jfrog.com/artifactory/) on our server, I have been alone in using my account (which is separate from `admin` account) to deploy to a library in `libs-release-local`, and everything works fine.

Yesterday, I setup an account for my colleague to work with, giving them the same configuration as my own account, which is simply being member of a group that can contribute to _everything. This group has `Delete/Overwrite`, `Deploy/Cache`, `Annotate` and `Read` access to `libs-release-local`.

We are using `gradlew` to build and release our lib. When using their username/encrypted password to download the artifacts or deploy a version, our server directly returns a `401` response to `GET|/api/system/version|HTTP/1.1|`. Keeping on the same computer, if we just switch to my credentials in the `gradle.properties` file, I can login successfully.

We have tried changing their password a few times, each time taking the new encrypted one to try, but the result stays the same. Of course, they can also successfully login to the webapp. We have run out of ideas on what could be incorrect in our configuration.

Comment: Maybe there's a way to add verbosity to the `gradlew` command line. Try setting the [`logging` to `DEBUG`](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/logging.html) passing `-d` parameter. There's probably a way to listen on the network with a reverse proxy to catch the exact request to the `GET /api/system/version` and maybe find out some more details. You should also mention versions of each tools in here in case it could help. Maybe you can try different versions of both tools.

Comment: Thank you! However the issue resolved itself this morning after yet another password change. I suspect Artifactory doesn't like certain special characters, although I have no proof. Therefore I will close this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue resolved itself this morning after yet another password change. I suspect Artifactory doesn't like certain special characters, although I have no proof.

I will use this "answer" to close the question, but I'll accept any answer that confirms my suspicion or suggests to the actual cause or the problem.